# Issues with VS Code Durable Function Monitor Plugin and Azure Functions Core Tools Version

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm having some issues with the Durable Function Monitor plugin for Visual Studio Code.

When I'm using Azure Functions Core Tools v3, I get this error message when I try to launch the plugin:

"Default backend now requires at least Azure Functions Core Tools v4.0.4629 (currently discovered is v3.0.4899). Install latest Azure Functions Core Tools or, alternatively, select a custom backend in extension's settings"

Following this advice, I updated to Core Tools v4. However, when I try to launch with v4, I get the following error:

"No response within 60 seconds. Ensure you have the latest Azure Functions Core Tools installed globally."

I've confirmed that I do have the latest version installed globally, but I'm still encountering the same issue. Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi @Alpha24, problems caused by Core Tools version conflicts have been discussed as part of this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor/issues/75 . If those recommendations still don't help, then I suggest you create another issue and provide logs from "Durable Functions Monitor" output channel. And anyway, you can always explicitly provide path to the correct Core Tools version via "Custom Path To Azure Functions Host" setting.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Durable Functions Monitor plugin in my VS Code and it was launched successfully, Refer below:-

As a pre-requisite make sure you have the latest version of Azure Functions Core tool downloaded from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).  and you have Azure account extension installed in the VS Code like below:-

**Pre-requisite:-**

[image]

**Azure Account extension:-**

[image]

Sign in to your Azure account containing your Durable Functions and After you install Durable Function Monitor extension it will be reflected in your VS Code left pane. As I have signed in into my Azure account containing Durable Functions the Monitoring extension is launched successfully like below:-

***Monitoring of one of the Durable Functions in my account is successful. Refer below:-***

[image]

***After you install this Extension, Close your VS Code and Open it again, Sign into your Azure account in the tenant where your Durable Function exist. If the issue persists, Uninstall the extension close the VS Code, Open the VS Code and install the extension again***

My Azure Function Core tool version:-

**Command :-**

```bash
func --version
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Azure Function Core tools is part of my Envrionment Settings in my machine like below:-

[image]

Note- Make sure you're not connected to any Proxy or VPN also check your internet connection as the extension takes time to load the  Functions Monitor tab.

> Reference:- [GitHub - microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor: A
> monitoring/debugging UI tool for Azure Durable Functions](https://github.com/microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor)

Comment: I was installing core tools with my npm but it wasn't installing anything so had to do it with the .msi and it did works